# How to add try catch block in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin.I want to add try catch block for exception handling in my jQuery plug-in.

My plug-in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.requiredclass').keyup(function() {


$(this).pluginMethod();

});
});

(function($) {  //i Want try catch block for this part

// jQuery plugin definition

$.fn.pluginMethod = function(e) {

       return this.each(function() {
       var $this = $.this; 
       var som= $this.val();

            //My Code goes here  

        });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Now if I want to add try catch block then how the plugin will look like?
In case of jquery function We do something like this

the function

```
function myFunction() {
//varible declarations
try { 
    //Code goes here
}
catch(err) {  //We can also throw from try block and catch it here
    alert("err");
}
finally {
    //code for finally block
}
}
```

Now this is the format we know in case of a function.But what will be the format if I want to add exception handling in a plug in? In the plugin from `(function($) {` the plugin starts then there is `$.fn.pluginMethod = function(e) {` followed by

```
       return this.each(function() {`. So where to start the try block and stop it,where to put catch block.Can any one suggest me the format.
```

If any one have any doubt in understanding the question please let me know,I will try to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think i really get your question. You need to be more clear.

But is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.requiredclass').keyup(function() {
    $(this).pluginMethod();
    });
});


try { 
    (function($) {
        //jQuery plugin definition
        $.fn.pluginMethod = function(e) {

           return this.each(function() {
               var $this = $.this; 
               var som= $this.val();
               //your Code goes here
           });
        };

    })(jQuery);
} catch(err) {  
    alert("err");
} finally {
    //code for finally block
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
 try{
(function($) { 

// jQuery plugin definition

$.fn.pluginMethod = function(e) {

       return this.each(function() {
       var $this = $.this; 
       var som= $this.val();

            //My Code goes here  

        })(jQuery);
}
catch(error)
{
alert(error);
}
```

Comment: At the end of the this (function($) { I have   })(jQuery); So do I need to complete the try block after  })(jQuery);.

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    //Block of code to try
}
catch(err) {
   // Block of code to handle errors
}
```